# Set default value for checkbox in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular JS and working on creating a table where dynamic rows can be added. The new row contains a checkbox which should default to selected (value=Y). For existing data it should show what comes up from DB (Y or N)

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="safetyCheck.needed" 
        value="{{safetyCheck.needed}}" />
```

I tried adding `ng-checked="safetyCheck==Y"` and set `$safetyCheck:Y` when pushing a new blank row. But this always results in Y even if users unselects the component. how can i fix this.

Comment: Read the docs for checkbox. You can't use `ng-checked` with `ng-model`

Comment: thanks , @charlietfl I saw the same. Is there anyother way to do it ?

Comment: Another way to do what? You clearly didn't read docs thoroughly

Comment: for new rows i push to the table i have to set default values as selected. I was using ng-checked to set this in the controller I was setting safetycheck.needed as Y for new rows. since i cant use ng-checked how do i set default values

Answer (score 2):

For specific check\uncheck values use [ng-true-value & ng-false-value](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D) arguments:

```
<input type="checkbox"
    ng-model="safetyCheck.needed"
    ng-true-value="'Y'"
    ng-false-value="'N'"/>
```

Comment: but then how do i set default checked to new rows

Comment: @yjoe How You add new rows? I think something like this: `$scope.rowsArray.push({needed: 'Y'});` in controller;

Comment: yes , thats exactly what I have now. but when i save data even if I unselect the values still goes as Y

Comment: Maybe You problem in namespaces? [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fOdM0gsLQ42KTBOxWYrm?p=preview);

Comment: Perfect man! I didn't know about this "ng-true-value" and "ng-false-value", this is the right approach. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`ng-checked` should not be used together with `ng-model`. Instead just initialize the variable to true preferably in the controller or wherever you are adding the rows. (Or even in an `ng-init` as follows)

```
<input type="checkbox"
ng-model="safetyCheck.needed"
ng-init="safetyCheck.needed=true"/>
```

Comment: For what it's worth.  I found this useful when trying to get a check box to default to 0.  ng-false-value only seemed to set for me if a user checked and then unchecked.  ng-init="my.model=0" worked.